# Monitor for category/folder change in Outlook with Python

Tags: python, outlook, activex, win32com, dispatch

I am looking to build a Python tool that monitors category and folder changes in Outlook.

So far I managed to hook into the OnNewMailEx event and monitor for all incoming emails using the code below:

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import re

def getPath(folder, path=[]):
    if folder.parent.parent.parent:
        path.append(folder.name)
        getPath(folder.parent, path)
    return "\\".join(reversed(path))

class Handler_Class(object):
    def OnNewMailEx(self, receivedItemsIDs):
        for ID in receivedItemsIDs.split(","):
            mailItem = outlook.Session.GetItemFromID(ID)
            if re.search("(TS)|(ST)", mailItem.Parent.FolderPath) != None:
                print "Subj: " + mailItem.Subject
                print "Time: " + str(mailItem.ReceivedTime)
                print "Parent: " + str(mailItem.Parent.FolderPath)
                # print "Body: " + mailItem.Body.encode( 'ascii', 'ignore' )
                print "========"

outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class)
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Now I am trying to expand this to hook into the events that monitor category changes. MSDN has this on the subject: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olkcategory.aspx

However, when I tried the code below (with the correct names from http://svn.cy55.de/changeset/1896?format=diff&new=1896), nothing happens:

```
class Handler_Class(object):
    def OnChange(self):
        print("Hook successful!")    

category = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.OlkCategoryStrip", Handler_Class)
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Furthermore, I can't find any documentation for events that monitor if an email was moved to a different folder. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OlkCategory interface you are referencing is tied to the Categories control that is used in Outlook Form Regions; it's useless by itself.  To monitor property changes (including Categories) of an item you need to hook into the MailItem.PropertyChange event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866739.aspx.

To monitor when an item is added to a folder you need to trap the Items.ItemAdd event for any given folder: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869609.aspx.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for coming back. A couple of questions: 1. How do you hook into the "PropertyChange"/"ItemAdd" event? I don't think it's as simple as adding a def OnPropertyChange(self, name) to my handler_Class above? Do I need to create a new "DispatchWithEvents"? 2. Can I track WHO changed the property/moved the item?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Python.  All I can say is that PropertyChange is an event of the MailItem class and ItemAdd is a property of the Items collection class (retrieved from a Folder object's Items property). The "who" would always be the current user, which you can get via the NameSpace.CurrentUser property.

Comment: Hi, so how would you hook into these event in VBA?

Comment: Declare the object that you want to subscribe to events at the top of the module or class. E.g. Dim WithEvents myMailItem As MailItem. The dropdown for the myMailItem in the IDE will show all of the available events, and choosing one will create an event stub.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866235.aspx

Comment: Hey @EricLegault my current program categorizes the incoming emails to a particular category in outlook. The program runs as a cron or a deamon continously and categorizes the incoming emails.
Now after my categorization is done, people then go through the categorized emails and they modify the categories if they are wrongly categorized by the program . I have to monitor and capture this change in the category which is done manually. In my current setup i am not able to integrate how to track this change which is done manually. Please advise a mechanism to capture this change.

Comment: You can trap the ItemChange event for items in the containing folder: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865866.aspx